# Dense subalgebra intersection with essential ideal is dense?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Consider $A$ is an unital C* algebra, $D$ is a dense *-subalgebra, $B$ is a essential,maximal ideal of $A$. Is $D\cap B$ dense in $B$?

I have seen this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1545705/is-intersection-of-a-dense-subspace-and-a-closed-subspace-of-a-hilbert-space-als/1546849), and this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73142/dense-subalgebras-of-c-algebras-and-their-intersections-with-sub-c-algebras), but my assumption is little bit different, so I think I am asking a different question here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Certanily not.  Consider $A=C([0, 1])$,  $$B=\{f\in  A: f(0)=0\},$$ and $D=\mathbb C\cdot 1$.

---

**EDIT**.
OK, so here is a counter-example satisfying  the new requirement that $D$ be a dense subalgebra.

$\newcommand{\F}{\mathbb F_2}$
Let $\F$ be the free group on two generators, and let:

- $A$ be the full group C$^*$-algebra of $\F$, often also denoted by $C^*(\F)$,
- $B$ be the kernel of the left-regular representation $\lambda :C^*(\F)\to C_r^*(\F)$, and
- $D$ be the canonical copy of the complex group algebra $\mathbb C(G)$ within $C^*(\F)$.

Then

1. $B\cap D$ is not dense in $B$,  and in fact  $B\cap D=\{0\}$.

**Reason**.  This is because the restriction of $\lambda $ to $\mathbb C(G)$ is injective.

2. $B$ is a maximal ideal of $C^*(\F)$.

**Reason**.  This is because $C_r^*(\F)$ is simple,  thanks to a well known result by Powers [1].

3. $B$ is an  essential ideal.

**Reason**.  This is the hardest point to justify:  arguing by contradiction,  suppose that $J$ is a nontrivial ideal in $C^*(\F)$,
trivially intersecting $B$.  Then $\lambda (J)$ is a nontrivial ideal in  $C_r^*(\F)$,  so necessarily $\lambda (J)=C_r^*(\F)$, by
simplicity.

It follows that $\lambda $ restricts to an isomprphism from $J$ to $C_r^*(\F)$, and hence  the inverse of that restriction is  an
injective *-homomorphism
$$
  \mu :C_r^*(\F)\to C^*(\F).
  $$

By Choi's Theorem [2], $C^*(\F)$ admits a separating family of finite dimensional representations (this is to say that  $C^*(\F)$ is
residually finite dimensional), so the same applies to $C_r^*(\F)$.  However, since the latter is simple and infinite
dimensional, we see that it has no finite dimensional representation whatsoever.  This is a contradiction.

[1] *Powers, Robert T.*, [**Simplicity of the C$^*$-algebra associated with the free
group on two generators**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1215/S0012-7094-75-04213-1), Duke Math. J. 42, 151-156
(1975). [ZBL0342.46046](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0342.46046).

[2] *Choi, Man-Duen*, [**The full C$^*$-algebra of the free group on two
generators**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2140/pjm.1980.87.41), Pac. J. Math. 87, 41-48
(1980). [ZBL0463.46047](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0463.46047).

Comment: May you elaborate how is $B$ essential?

Comment: Sorry but I have edited the $D$ must be dense right now.